# Rename file after putHDFS

Tags: hdfs, apache-nifi

I have apache NIFI job where I get file from system using `getFile` then I use `putHDFS`, how can I rename the file in HDFS after putting the file in hadoop ?
I tried to use `executeScript` processor but can't get it to work

```
flowFile = session.get()
if flowFile != None:
    tempFileName= flowFile.getAttribute("filename")
    fileName=tempFileName.replace('._COPYING_','')
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'filename', fileName)
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer above by Shu is correct for how to manipulate the filename attribute in NiFi, but if you have already written a file to HDFS and then use UpdateAttribute, it is not going to change the name of the file in HDFS, it will only change the value of the filename attribute in NiFi.

You could use the UpdateAttribute approach to create a new attribute called "final.filename" and then use MoveHDFS to move the original file to the final file.

Also of note, the PutHDFS processor already writes a temp file and moves it to the final file so I'm not sure if it is necessary for you to name ".*COPYING*". For example if you send a flow file to PutHDFS with filename of "foo" it will first write ".foo" to the directory and when done it will move it to "foo".

The only case where you need to use MoveHDFS is if some other process is monitoring the directory and can't ignore the dot files, then you write it somewhere else and use MoveHDFS once it is complete.

Comment: Thanks alot Bryan, this is exactly the case am facing, I have storm listening on a HDFS directory where Apache Nifi is loading data ...
Storm only has the ability to ignoreSuffix ... this is why am appending the "__COPYING__".
on the other hand , I can't find the moveHDFS in my ApacheNifi processors

Comment: What version of NiFi are you using? It was added in 1.5.0, here is the JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-3366

Comment: am using version 1.0.0

Comment: Ok I know upgrading is hard, but 1.0.0 is fairly old at this point, the latest release is 1.7.1.. the only other alternative is if you have the hadoop client installed on same machine as NiFi then you can use ExecuteScript to issue a hdfs mv through a script

Comment: this is the command am trying to use now 
hadoop fs -mv "{$filename}" "${filename%._COPYING_}"

Comment: Shouldn't the filenames be reversed? you have a file with COPYING and want to move it to a name without COPYING right? Also I think it should be "${filename}._COPYING_"

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using **ExecuteScript** processor(extra overhead) use **UpdateAttribute** processor Feed the Success relationship from PutHDFS

Add **new property** in UpdateAttribute processor as

**filename**

```
${filename:replaceAll('<regex_expression>','<replacement_value>')}
```

Use [replaceAll](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replaceall) function from NiFi Expression Language.

**(or)**

Using [replace](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#replace) Function

**filename**

```
${filename:replaceAll('<search_string>','<replacement_value>')}
```

[image]

NiFi expression language offers different functions to manipulate strings refer to [this](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#strings) link for more documentation related to expression language.

i have tried same **exact script that in Question** with **ExecuteScript** processor with **Script Engine as Python** and everything works as expected.

As you are using `.replace` function and replacing with `''`

**Output:**

[image]

As the filename `fn._COPYING_` got changed to `fn`.